# How to generate a repeating sequence of numbers in Google Sheet?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sequence, transpose

What I need is quite simple, yet somehow I can't get around to find a solution for it.

Basically what I need is for a column, starting from its second row to look list numbers from 1 to 15 and have that sequence repeated all the way to the bottom of the sheet automatically. I was thinking about using arrayformula but couldn't figure out the formula for it.

[image]

Essentially something like this but it goes all the way down automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Explanation:**

You can repeat ([REPT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094134?hl=en)) a sequence of numbers from `1` to `15` by using the [Sequence](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244?hl=en) formula.

The maximum number of times you want to repeat this sequence will be determined by the total number of rows in your sheet divided by `15`.

**Solution:**

```
=transpose(split(REPT(concat(JOIN(",",SEQUENCE(1,15)),","),ROUNDDOWN(ROWS(A1:A)/15)),",",true))
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

Comment: =TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(JOIN(",", SEQUENCE(1,15)) & ",", ROUNDDOWN(ROWS(A1:A)/15)), ","))

This is slightly more simpler version. Yields same result

Answer (score 1):

non-REPT solution:

```
=INDEX(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FLATTEN(
 SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(ROWS(A:A)/15), 15)-(
 SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(ROWS(A:A)/15), 1, 0)*15)), ROWS(A:A)-ROW()+1, 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but how about this?

```
=ArrayFormula(mod(row(A2:A)-1,15))
```

Comment: This didn't work as expected, for the first sequence it gives 1-14, then it gives 0-14. I was able to get it to mostly work with `=ArrayFormula(mod(row(A1:A100)-1,15)+1)` but that assumes you know what row you want it to end on (`A100` in that example)

Comment: @JoeLissner see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77518544/5632629

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

alternative:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(TOCOL(MAKEARRAY(ROWS(A2:A), 15, LAMBDA(x, y, y))), ROWS(A2:A), 1)
```

[image: enter iage description here]