# how to auto generate a sequence of words and numbers in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, numbers, google-sheets-formula, sequence, repeat

I need to categorize a list of "purchase orders" into "page and item numbers".
For example, Page1, Item1~7. I have found the way to do 1 simple sequence of numbers from the link below. But I can't figure out the way to do the "page numbers", and for more advance, adding an empty row between each page. Is it possible to just use the formula?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4Z48.jpg

[How to generate a repeating sequence of numbers in google sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64979292/how-to-generate-a-repeating-sequence-of-numbers-in-google-sheet)

Comment: This can definitely be done via a single formula, including the blank rows. However, you can help me/us help you by sharing a link to a sample spreadsheet containing the sample data shown to the left of your image and indicating where results should go. Just be sure to set the link's Share permission (when creating the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor," so that contributors can have full access to the sheet for the purposes of testing and leaving solutions.

Comment: Could you share the sheet so we can test different solutions? I recommend that you share it in viewer mode so that no user will find it modified and will not be able to use it correctly. We can all generate a copy of the sheet. It would also be useful to see a sample of the desired result, although it is entered manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment to the original post, it would have been more efficient to have had a link to a spreadsheet containing the starter data and an indication of where you wanted the results (same sheet? different sheet?). But in the interest of moving on, I'll suppose that your original header, "**purchase orders**" is in A1 and that your original purchase-order data runs A2:A.

Based upon those assumptions, the following formula will produce the two column headers and all results shown in your desired-results image:

`=ArrayFormula({"page_item",A1; IFERROR(VLOOKUP(FLATTEN("P"&SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(COUNTA(A2:A)/7))&"_#"&SEQUENCE(1,7+1)), {ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FLATTEN("P"&SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(COUNTA(A2:A)/7))&"_#"&SEQUENCE(1,7)),COUNTA(A2:A),1),FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")},{1,2},FALSE), {"",""})})`

It *can* go anywhere on the same sheet as written, but it probably makes the most sense to place it in the top cell of some otherwise empty column (e.g., C1).

[image]

If you want some other number of sections per page, just change the four instances of `7` in the formula to another number.

Obviously, if your real data isn't in Column A, you'll need to adjust the formula ranges to match your actual range.

As to *how* it works, that's a bit hard to explain; and this is such a custom functionality that I don't know that it will be widely sought or used by other site visitors. So let's make sure it's what you want first; and then, if you'd like an explanation, report back, and I'll get into it.

Comment: Sorry for my poor explanation! This is exactly what I need. I am amazed and impressed by your formula, I will spend some time to break it apart and study it. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. Yes, studying a formula yourself is always the best way to understand it and learn new "tricks" for future use.

Answer (score 0):

Assume PO = column A, page item = column b, PO = column c.

in B2 :

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()-1,8)=0,"","P"&INT((ROW()-1)/8+1)&"_#"&MOD(ROW()-1,8))
```

Idea : use row to drive the count.. mod(x,8) and small loop count & int(x/8+1) as big loop count.

in C2 :

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()-1,8)=0,"",OFFSET(A2,-1*COUNTBLANK($B$2:B2),0))
```

Idea : "how many empty cell in column B so far" = "the amount of shift needed to 'load' column A data".

Please share if it understandable/works/not.

Comment: It solves only problem of numbering but I think it's not that easy as you need also to add content of 2nd column in corresponding rows.

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out how to add empty row every 7th row but I figured out how to make a sequence and build a table without empty rows:

[image]

```
={ARRAYFORMULA("P"&ArrayFormula(CEILING(sequence(counta(B2:B))/7))&"_#"&array_constrain(transpose(split(rept("1|2|3|4|5|6|7|",counta(B2:B)),"|")),counta(B2:B),1)),
array_constrain(B2:B,counta(B2:B),1)}
```

My solution is available here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1owokwWW5OvN5VwZAWB5HvDxtBT82BqLJUMBnio9Gi2M/copy

Comment: Thank you very much, your formula also teaches me a lot.